# GitHub action in response to pull_request that doesn't create a status check?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-api, pull-request

I am trying to set up a GitHub action that will auto-merge PRs if they are in a mergeable state (pass all checks, etc).

My setup looks a bit like this:

```
name: Auto-Merge Pull Requests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened

jobs:
  auto_merge:
    name: auto_merge
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: ./.github/actions/auto_merge
```

Inside of the action, my rudimentary plan is to simply poll the GitHub API until the PR is in a clean state, or some timeout occurs.

However, I have discovered that this GitHub action is itself creating a pending status check on the PR, which only goes green once the action stops running. So I fundamentally cannot achieve what I want to, as the action itself places the PR in a non-mergeable state.

How can I run a GitHub Action without creating a new status check on the PR? I have looked all over the docs and cannot find any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this out myself, but [`pascalgn/automerge-action`](https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action) on GitHub might be worth using rather than rolling your own solution, as it also supports a bunch of extra features.

Comment: I've seen it, thanks. I need to roll my own for this particular use case, and am pretty surprised and disappointed at how difficult it's been.

Comment: I had a look at what this action is doing and it looks pretty involved. I agree that it might not be best to roll your own when it looks like there is already a well engineered solution. One option could be to fork the action and customise it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's not possible to avoid the status check when using `on: pull_request`. I would suggest trying to re-engineer your solution to use a different workflow trigger to perform the merge itself.

Perhaps `on: status` would work well in this case.
https://help.github.com/en/articles/events-that-trigger-workflows#status-event-status

From the API reference:

> The status API allows external services to mark commits with an `error`, `failure`, `pending`, or `success` state, which is then reflected in pull requests involving those commits.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/

If your workflow ran on `status` events and checked to see if the commit in question was in a success state, and contained in a PR, then that PR potentially could be merged.

Comment: I've tried all of the above, and arrived at the conclusion that polling after `pull_request` is the only reasonable solution without using `check_run`. Moreover, there is an undocumented field called `mergeable_status` that this whole thing relies on. It essentially returns a string which _kind of_ indicates if the PR is blocked from merge or not. TLDR: GitHub actions are still in beta and are essentially a mess. I'd advise others to wait.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running your workflow on a different event for example run only if merge request is approved. This also does not adds a `status check`

```
name: Auto-Merge Pull Requests

on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  auto_merge:
    name: auto_merge
    if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: ./.github/actions/auto_merge
```